# Found the public method "add", but did not find a public "remove" in symfony2 entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I get this exeption when I submit my form:

```
Found the public method "addRemote", but did not find a public "removeRemote" on class App\CoreBundle\Entity\Scene
```

The weired think is that the remove method exist ...
But i wrote it myself (When I did php app/console doctrine:generate:entities) doctrine didn't generated it. Did I make something wrong ?

```
 /**
 * @var array $remote
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="remote", type="array", nullable=true)
 */
private $remote;


/**
 * Set remote
 *
 * @param array $remote
 * @return Scene
 */
public function addRemote($value, $key=null) {
    if($key!=null){
        $this->remote[$key] = $value;
    }else{
        $this->remote[] = $value;
    }
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove remote
 */
public function removeRemote(){
    unset($this->remote);   
}
```

I allso tried:

```
    /**
     * Remove remote
     */
    public function removeRemote($key=null){
        if($key!=null && array_key_exists($key, $this->remote)){
            unset($this->remote[$key]);
        }
        unset($this->remote);

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: just a wild guess here, maybe it doesnt "register" the method because it is not returning anything

Comment: I think removeSomething requires a parameter to specify the element to remove.

Comment: @SamJanssens I've added a return statment but still ...

Comment: @Pazi It was my first try ! I would like to be able to remove just specified index, but as it didn't worked I made it simplier ... See my edit

Comment: @Pazi I think you point out something ! if I dont set a default value to $key the exception disappear ! However I still dont get it ... why I can't have a default value ?

Comment: Puh, this was a little guess, from remembering such errors in past ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have bigger problem than this; you are abusing your forms :)

Add.. and Remove... methods should be used for relations, not columns as per your code. Also, both `add` and `remove` methods must accept parameter that will be either added or removed.

If you still need an array, than getRemotes() method should return key=>value array. Adder and remover will later get that key, based on what user have picked in `choice` form type.